# As sent to or as send to

Tags: tenses, conjugation

In the sentence:

> The invoices, as sent to the customers by mail.

When the invoices have already been sent. I suppose it would be `sent`. But when the sentence refers to the process of the sending in general,
would 'sent' be spelled with a `d` or a `t`? And what would the conjugation be?

Comment: The phrase, as quoted by you in your question, is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Sent* is the past participle of *send*, and that's what you would use regardless of the tense, as long as you're using the passive voice:

- The invoices **were sent** to the customers by mail. (This is roughly what your original sentence means.)
- The invoices **will be sent** to the customers by mail.
- The invoices **are sent** to the customers by mail.

However, if you switch to the active voice, you would conjugate *send* like this:

- We **sent** the invoices to the customers by mail.
- We **will send** the invoices to the customers by mail.
- We **send** the invoices to the customers by mail.